# How do I identify the lowest required visibility of methods?

Tags: delphi, refactoring

As part of a large refactoring project, I need to identify methods that are no longer used, or where the visibility can be reduced.

Consider the following code:

```
program Project1;

type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    function Method1 : integer;
  public
    function Method2 : integer;
    function Method3 : integer;
    function Method4 : integer;
  end;

var
  vMyObject : TMyClass;

function TMyClass.Method1: integer;
begin
  Result := Method2;
end;

function TMyClass.Method2: integer;
begin
  Result := 2;
end;

function TMyClass.Method3: integer;
begin
  Result := 3;
end;

function TMyClass.Method4: integer;
begin
  Result := 4;
end;

begin
  vMyObject := TMyClass.Create;
  try
    writeln(vMyObject.Method3);
  finally
    vMyObject.Free;
  end;
end.
```

The Delphi compiler gives the warning "[DCC Hint] Project1.dpr(6): H2219 Private symbol 'Method1' declared but never used", which is very helpful. But there are other issues with this code that I would like to be warned about:

1. Method4 is never used, but I don't get a warning since it's public.
2. Method2 is declared public, but only used privately.

Are there any tools I can use to identify issues like these?

Comment: Rename the method and compile, if no one complains it can be removed, if only the same unit complains it can be made private.

Comment: Yes, but I would have to do this for every method. I was hoping to identify all at once.

Comment: I figured you'd have a reason, that's why it is a comment :).

Comment: I guess [PAL from Peganza](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm) and/or [CodeHealer](http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php) might be able to help you.

Comment: What Delphi SKU do you have? IIRC Archidect has some code metrics stuff which might have reports you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm) can do it and much more cases.

Comment: Thanks. I bought a licence for PAL (the evaluation version was far to limited to do a thorough evaluation), and it looks very good so far.

Answer (score 1):

[PAL from Peganza](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm) and/or [CodeHealer](http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php) might be able to help you.